# Checking if a string is a palindrome (CodeSignal test case problem)

Tags: c, string

I'm using CodeSignal to test my coding abilities, but I've come across a problem.

Right now, I'm trying to check if a string is a palindrome.

I have already written code that should work, but 1 test case keeps failing . So, `19/20` test cases work correctly, but the last one does not (not sure which one, it's hidden to prevent hardcoding).

```
checkPalindrome(char * inputString) {
    char temp[strlen(inputString) + 1];
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = strlen(inputString) - 1; i >= 0; i--, d++)
        temp[d] = inputString[i];
    if (strcmp(temp, inputString) == 0)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure why 1 test case keeps failing, I've tested a numerous amount of strings in CodeBlocks, and they seem to be right.

Comment: With `for (int i = strlen(inputString) - 1`, how does a null terminator make it onto the copy?

Comment: There is one more problem - suppose that I give a string of 16 MiB. You will create that array on the stack, and totally overflow it...  you don't need a *copy*, instead just use the loop to *check the characters* until you meet in the middle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in the loop. If `inputString` is empty, `strlen(inputString)` is unsigned long 0. In case of operators between unsigned and signed return unsigned, both arguments are casted to unsigned.  So, `(unsigned long)0 - (int)1` is `(unsigned long)0 - (unsigned long)1`, which is 2<sup>64</sup>-1 (if `unsigned long` is 8-byte).

Beware of operators between signed and unsigned numbers!

I know even worse example:

```
int foo = -1;
unsigned bar = 0;

if (foo >= bar)
    cout << "-1 >= 0" << endl;
else
    cout << "-1 < 0" << endl;
```

Guess what this code prints.

PS: what is written in the comment is also true.

Answer (score 0):

Running your for loop on one variable instead of two variables would be a better implementation.

```
 checkPalindrome(char * inputString) {
 int len = strlen(inputString);
 char temp[len+1];
 temp[len] = '\0';
 for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    temp[i] = inputString[len-1-i];
 }
 if (strcmp(temp, inputString) == 0)
    return 1;
 else return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AntoineMathys thank you and Meiogordo for editing . Just refreshed my memory about C strings.

Answer (score -1):

C Solution

```
bool checkPalindrome(char * s) {
    char *q = s + strlen(s) - 1;

    while (q > s) {
        if (*q-- != *s++)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

JavaScript Solution

1. Given minimum string length is > 1
2. Take two pointers pointing to first and last character of a string
3. Compare pointer characters & Keep increasing the first pointer and keep decreasing the last pointer until both pointers meet
4. Return false if characters don't match else return true
5. O(n) time | O(1) space complexities

```
function checkPalindrome(inputString) {

    if(inputString.length === 1)

        return true

    let leftIdx = 0

    let rightIdx = inputString.length - 1

    while(leftIdx < rightIdx) {

        if(inputString[leftIdx] === inputString[rightIdx]) {

            leftIdx++;

            rightIdx--;

        } else 

            return false;

    }

    return true;


}
```

Comment: How would a JavaScript solution help in case of C language

Comment: It may help Javascript coders and as I have explained in comments can help in finding algorithm and calculation of time and space complexities

Comment: Posted C language solution too

Comment: Please do upvote as I have posted C language solution too and all test cases passed